# How to restore old egg file when upgrade fails?

Tags: python, pip, egg

I installed a package `xxx-1.0` using `pip` and it installed the egg file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xxx-1.0-py2.7.egg`.
After upgrading the package, the file `xxx-1.0-py2.7.egg` was replaced by `xxx-2.0-py2.7.egg`.
But the upgrade failed.  When I tried upgrade again, `pip` saw the file `xxx-1.0-py2.7.egg` and complained that it's already installed.
By removing the egg file manually, I can upgrade but I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to let `pip` restore the original egg file when an upgrade fails?

Comment: `sudo pip install xxYYxxxx --upgrade --exists-action b` Meaning upgrade it if old, create a backup if exists(`--exists-action b`).

Comment: Perhaps `pip install PACKAGE --upgrade --force-reinstall`? It doesn't restore the original, but it should reinstall the package.

Comment: "linux freak" ? well, put /usr/local/lib/python2.7 on a dedicated LVM partition, then use LVM snapshots ? :)

Comment: 1)How did the upgrade "fail" (metadata-wise)? What does `pip list` show? 2)How do you have `.egg`s if you're using `pip`? It installs them unpacked by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reinstall a particular version you can specify it with `pip install xxx==1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `.egg`, you effectively have a distribution. So,

- remove the `2.0` installation

  - what is needed to do that depends on how the upgrade "failed"
- then `pip install` the old `.egg`

  - not needed if the upgrade "failed" in such a manner that it's still listed as installed